# "Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)" does not appear as an option for "Portable Document Format (PDF)"

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I need to be able to use FDF's in PDF's and to do so I need to use Adobe Acrobat as Firefox's built-in PDF viewer doesn't FDF's. Problem is... that option is no longer appearing. "Use Adobe Acrobat (default)" appears as an option but not "Use Adobe Acrobat (in Firefox)".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that Adobe Reader is installed in your PC and you've updated Firefox latest version!

[image]